# ZOOM UAC-2 : No sound

Tags: sound, audio

**Issue:**

Downloaded the latest version of EOS today, started the OS up in tryout mode from USB and all works fine, except for audio.

**Troubleshoot**

- Set my ZOOM UAC-2 audio interface to class compliant mode
- via terminal: alsamixer, F6 & select ZOOM UAC-2, exit
- Go to system > sound & check output devices, mutes etc. I see the meters registering sound, but there is no sound coming out of the speakers & headphone

What am I missing?
Any help appreciated.